# How can I make my OpenCV code work without becoming stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video

I'm a new coder and I work on graduation project with OpenCV library [Python code].

I need to write code to detect balloon in the constant background and monitor it.

I decided to work with Substruct function + HoughCircles, the problem is that every code is working good [except the Circle detection which working not the best], When I combine the two codes It works super slowly and stuck ALOT, can someone suggest me please how to insert it right so it wont stuck and somehow improve the HoughCircles?

```
    import numpy as np
    #import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    import cv2

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

    while True:

        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if frame is None:
            break

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(gray)

        #changes = sum(sum(fgmask>200))
        changes = (fgmask>200).sum() #
        is_moving = (changes > 10000)
        print(changes, is_moving)



        items = []

        contours, hier = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        for cnt in contours:
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            if 200 < area:
                (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                cv2.rectangle(fgmask, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),255, 2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0), 2)
                items.append( (area, x, y, w, h) )

        if items:
            main_item = max(items)
            area, x, y, w, h = main_item
            if w > h:
                r = w//2
            else:
                r = h//2
            cv2.circle(frame, (x+w//2, y+h//2), r, (0,0,255), 2)
            print(x + w // 2, y + h // 2)

        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,50,
                              param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
        #circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        if circles is not None:
            # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

            # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
            for (x, y, r) in circles:
                # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle in the image
                # corresponding to the center of the circle
                cv2.circle(gray, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
                #cv2.rectangle(gray, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
                # time.sleep(0.5)
                print("Column Number: ")
                print(x)
                print("Row Number: ")
                print(y)
                print("Radius is: ")
                print(r)

        cv2.imshow('fgmask', fgmask)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.imshow('gray',gray)

        k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Save a few frames. Write unit tests for createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2 
 and HoughCircles. Verify they both produce desired result on each frame, and that they both produce the result quickly. Break out helper functions where convenient.

Comment: You can try commenting out a block to pinpoint the performance issue. Sometimes printing to console makes the issue worse, i.e. printing a diagnostic 30 times per second.